# Prove existence of continuous function on $(0,1)$ with special properties

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the interval $I=(0,1)$ and let $f,g$ be two linearly independent continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

I am asking if there is a continuous function $h$ such that 
$$\int_0^1 h(s) f(s) ds=0$$

$$\int_0^1 h(s) g(s) ds \neq 0$$

and $h(0)=h(1)=0$.

If it were only the first two conditions, then Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization would do the job, but it seems to be difficult to incorporate the third condition in this framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can just work with the measure $d\mu(x) = x(1-x)\, dx$. By Gram-Schmidt, there is a function $\tilde{h}$ such that
$$
\int_0^1 \tilde{h}(x) \, f(x) \, x(1-x) \, dx =0,
$$
$$
\int_0^1 \tilde{h}(x) \, g(x) \, x(1-x) \, dx \neq 0.
$$
The function $\tilde{h}$ is explicit, using the scalar product given by $\mu$.
$$
\tilde{h} = g - {\langle g, f\rangle \over \langle f, f \rangle} f.
$$
Then take $h(x) = x(1-x)\tilde{h}(x)$.